# Wordpress custom search query

Tags: wordpress

We have written a completely custom search for WordPress as we had very extensive needs for this.

The way it works is that when someone search, we execute our own **query** (custom mysql statement, including several `UNION`s). This all works fine, however, for particular queries, we can't reach `/page/2?s=***`. This page doesn't even end up on the search page, but goes to 404.

My assumption is that WordPress is first doing a search themselves and then also calculation how many results are to be shown, but because some search don't have any or enough results, the second page is not available.

It seems to me that the solution would be to replace the default WordPress search itself be our code, but I can't find anything online about actually replacing the search by your own query. Is this possible?

Alternatively, are there any ways how we can allow the `/page/2/?s=` to go to the search page, where our code will handle the rest? Instead of getting a 404.

Comment: '`particular queries`' means your example '***' or you simply cant reach further pages with different queries? And how did you rewrite the search? And how does your pagination within search looks like?

Comment: Particular queries = just a search for a particular string, e.g. "ksno", not "***". We are building a plain old `SELECT ...` and then using `$wpdb->get_results( $q, OBJECT );`

Comment: page 1 and page 2 search results/pages/links are called Pagination. Other things to consider are type of Request. ie GET vs POST search results. Maybe this WordPress Codex page will be helpful:  https://codex.wordpress.org/Making_Custom_Queries_using_Offset_and_Pagination

Comment: Oh and forgot to mention that there are a few WordPress plugins that do advanced searches where you can choose custom search results so maybe you can use one of those pre-made plugin solutions or at least look at the code in one of those plugins to figure out what you need for your custom search script/query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on how you are generating paginated links to more search results, I would recommend using a $_GET parameter to determine the current page, defaulting to page 1.

If you are using your own page template to render the search results, this is probably the most straightforward way to work around WordPress's default pagination functions:

```
/?s=search_here&s_page=1
```

For example.  I have done this with custom plugins that have search and paginated results handled in a single page template.